# Prolog Problems with inquiries

Tags: prolog

I'm doing inquiries in Prolog, this is the answer.

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| brasil | chile |
| argentina | uruguay |
| uruguay | argentina |
| chile | brasil |

But I need the answer to be

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| brasil | chile |
| uruguay | argentina |

This is the code.

```
limitrofes(X,Y):- 
    limita_con(X,Y)
    ; limita_con(Y,X).

translimitrofes(X,Y) :-
    limitrofes(X,Z),
    limitrofes(Z,Y),
    dif(X,Y).
```

and this is the inquiries

```
?- translimitrofes(X,Y).
```

Thank you

Comment: Remove `; limita_con(Y,X)` - or create a new predicate for this particular purpose which doesn't have that line.

Comment: I tried it, but when I query translimitrofes(X,Y).   It brings me back only brasil and chile and false

I don't know why it brings me back false :c


Can you help me please ?

Comment: `false` at that point only means that it looked for another solution but didn't find another solution. It's not a problem. Show all your relevant code, so we can help with it.

Comment: This is all the code

es_un_pais(uruguay).
es_un_pais(chile).
es_un_pais(paraguay).
es_un_pais(argentina).

%Superficie
superficie_pais(brasil,8547404).
superficie_pais(uruguay,176000).

limita_con(brasil,argentina).
limita_con(brasil,uruguay).
limita_con(argentina,chile).

% Reglas

pais_pequeño(X):-superficie_pais(X,Y),Y<1000000.                                  
limitrofes(X,Y):- limita_con(X,Y);limita_con(Y,X).
translimitrofes(X,Y):- limitrofes(X,Z),limitrofes(Z,Y), dif(X,Y), not(limitrofes(X,Y)).